# Change 'ethers' version in specific dependencies

Tags: npm, version-control, npm-install, ethers.js, hardhat

Suppose i run `npm ls ethers` to get version of ethers in hardhat project, the result is as follow :-

```
├─┬ @nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox@3.0.0
│ ├─┬ @nomicfoundation/hardhat-chai-matchers@2.0.1
│ │ └── ethers@6.7.0 deduped
│ ├─┬ @nomicfoundation/hardhat-ethers@3.0.4
│ │ └── ethers@6.7.0 deduped
│ ├─┬ @typechain/ethers-v6@0.4.3
│ │ └── ethers@6.7.0 deduped
│ ├─┬ @typechain/hardhat@8.0.3
│ │ └── ethers@6.7.0 deduped
│ ├── ethers@6.7.0
│ └─┬ hardhat-gas-reporter@1.0.9
│   └─┬ eth-gas-reporter@0.2.25
│     └── ethers@4.0.49
└─┬ hardhat@2.17.1
  ├─┬ @nomicfoundation/ethereumjs-block@5.0.1
  │ └── ethers@5.7.2
  └─┬ @nomicfoundation/ethereumjs-statemanager@2.0.1
    └── ethers@5.7.2
```

Now i want to change the **ethers** version in first 5 entities i.e. @nomicfoundation/hardhat-chai-matchers@2.0.1, @nomicfoundation/hardhat-ethers@3.0.4, @typechain/ethers-v6@0.4.3, @typechain/hardhat@8.0.3 and ethers@6.7.0 from **ethers@6.7.0** to **ethers@5.7.2**.

I am trying `npm install ethers@5.7.2 --save-dev`, but as ethers itself comes with **hardhat-toolbox**, doing this way to make changes in 'ethers version' results in version conflicts in terminal.

Is there any way we can change the version of ethers in the mentioned 5 entities?

Answer (score 0):

you should go to your package.json file and change the ethers different versions from there and run `npm install` command

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).